# How find the value of $f(n)=P_{n-1}^{1}-P_{n-1}^{2}+P_{n-1}^3+\cdots+(-1)^{n}P_{n-1}^{n-1}$

Tags: calculus

let 
$ $

show that $f(n)$  is Polynomial and such The coefficient of
is integer ,and Find the $f(n)$ close form.

where $$P_{n}^{r}=\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!}$$

My try:

it is easy to know $P_{n}^{r}=(n)(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-r+1)$ is Polynomial of $n$,and the coefficient is integer,

so
I think $f(n)$ is Polynomial of $n$,and  the coefficient is integer too.But How find the close form $f(n)$?

Answer (score 0):

What this problem reduces to [If $n$ is even] is:
$$f(n)=(n-1)!{({1\over0!}-{1\over1!}+{1\over2!}-{1\over3!}+\cdots)}$$

Which becomes:
$$f(n)=(n-1)!{(e^{-1})}$$
This is not the exact answer but should give an approximate idea of the answer.